# How to use multiple datasources that rely on each other in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm making a website with 2 dropdown lists, one is connected to a datasource that displays the names of all products, the second displays the company name of all customers (northwind).

After both options are selected, a button is hit which displays a gridview that shows the orderid, orderdate, shipdate, and quantity if there is an order from that customer (dropdownlist2) where they ordered that product (dropdownlist1), otherwise I'll have a validator set up if that scenario hasn't happened.

**What I don't understand is how to get the 3rd datasource's SQL to be dynamic, since it needs to use what's in the 2 dropdown lists as conditions. So far this is what I have:**

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GridView1.Visible = True

    Dim v1, v2 As String
    v1 = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString
    v2 = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value.ToString

    SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "select O.OrderID, OrderDate, ShippedDate, Quantity" _
                                 & "from Orders O, [Order Details] D, Customers C, Products P" _
                                 & "where O.OrderID = D.OrderID" _
                                 & "and C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID" _
                                 & "and P.ProductID = D.ProductID" _
                                 & "and companyname = '" & v1 & "'" _
                                 & "and productname = '" & v2 & "'"

End Sub
```

---

Sorry if I'm going about all this wrong, this is my first time using StackOverflow

Comment: That code should work.  Do you get an error?

Comment: Use parameterized queries! http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx

Comment: I'm going to reiterate what @NikitaSilverstruk just said -- use parameterized queries. It prevents SQL injection attacks and allows the database to cache query execution plans.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example, assuming that `ddlTwo` is dependant on `ddlOne` and GridView `gv` is dependant on selection of both DropDownLists:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ddlOne.DataBind()
        ddlTwo.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlOne_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlOne.DataBinding
    sender.DataSource = someListOne
    sender.DataTextField = "TXT"
    sender.DataValueField = "ID"
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlTwo_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlTwo.DataBinding
    sender.DataSource = someListTwo
    sender.DataTextField = "TXT"
    sender.DataValueField = "ID"
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlOne_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlOne.SelectedIndexChanged
    ddlTwo.DataBind()
    gv.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlTwo_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlTwo.SelectedIndexChanged
    gv.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub gv_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gv.DataBinding
    sender.DataKeyNames = {"ID"}
    sender.DataSource = GetDataSource(ddlOne.SelectedValue, ddlTwo.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Also, as user2615302 mentioned, set the AutoPostBack option to True

Answer (score 0):

set your DropDownList1 AutoPostBack="True"
my guess they do not have a value there

Try debuging wuth a break point at the Sql query and See what the value of the query is