# First record in dropdown list will not update the other dropdownbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown box that is populated from results from a SQL query.  The selected value from dropdownlist1 successfully populates the lbAuthors dropdown list.  During testing I realized that the first record from dropdownlist1 never updates into the lbAuthors dropdownlist.  Here is an example:  if I have three authors name in the 2nd dropdown box (Frost, Kipling, Poe) the first name - Frost - does not update into the first dropdown box. Kipling or Poe do - but not Frost.

My question is - What do I need to include in my event to allow Frost (or whatever the first record is) to update into the first dropdown box? –

Code-behind:

```
protected void update_SelectedItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbAuthorList.Items.Clear();
    lbAuthorList.Items.Add(new ListItem(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
    lbAuthorList.Items.FindByValue(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text).Selected = true;
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
                  ID="lbAuthors" 
                  style="float:left;" 
                  DataSourceID="odsAuthorList" 
                  DataTextField="DisplayAuthorName" DataValueField="AuthorID" 
                  onselectedindexchanged="lbUserList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                  AppendDataBoundItems="True" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
                  runat="server" 
                  AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                  DataTextField="Display_AuthorName"  
                  EnableViewState="false"
                  DataValueField="Display_AuthorName"                  
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="update_SelectedItem" 
                  AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19528881/791952

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when you select the first item, selcted index does not change. You need to insert a dummy item like this::

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                  AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
                  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                  DataTextField="Display_AuthorName"  
                  EnableViewState="false"
                  DataValueField="Display_AuthorName"  
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="update_SelectedItem" 
                  AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue rises because u wrote code for dropdownlist changed but initially first value selected at that time dropdownlist changed event not fired. If u choose second and then choose first one it will work fine.

Just add one dummy variable in dropdownlist item..

dropdownlist1.Items.Add("--Select--");